# Connectivity of complements of Stein opens

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $Y$ be an affine open subset of a locally noetherian scheme $X$. Then, $X \setminus Y$ has pure codimension one [EGAIV$_4$, Cor. 21.12.7]. Moreover, if $X$ is proper and of finite type over a field $k$, and $\dim X \ge 2$, then $X \setminus Y$ is connected [[Hartshorne](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=282977), Cor. II.6.2].

My question is the following:

> If $X$ is a complex projective variety of dimension $\ge 2$, and $Y$ is a Zariski open
>   subset that is Stein, then is it still true that $X \setminus Y$ is
>   connected?

The fact that $X \setminus Y$ is of pure codimension one is [[Neeman](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=932296), Prop. 3.4], and is a consequence of Hartog's theorem. Jing Zhang cites this proposition for the statement that $X \setminus Y$ is connected in [Algebraic Stein Varieties](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2424914), specifically in the proof of Thm. 2.8, but it is not clear to me how Neeman's proposition implies this result.

It could also be true that the algebraic proof when $Y$ is affine can be modified in the case when $Y$ is Stein instead. But a key step in the proof by Hartshorne (and Goodman in his [original article](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=242843)) is that we can embed $Y$ into an affine space $\mathbf{A}^n$, then take its projective closure $\overline{Y}$ to get a compactification of $Y$, and compare this with $X$ using theorems about blow-ups from Nagata's [paper on compactifications](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=142549). I can't make this work in the Stein case.

Comment: Let $X$ be a variety. (I presume this means that $X$ is irreducible.) Since $X$ is irreducible, it follows that any non-empty open $U$ of $X$ is irreducible (and thus connected). Thus, to make your question non-trivial, it might be useful to emphasize that $X$ is not assumed to be irreducible.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I'm a bit confused—I'm asking about the connectivity of $X \setminus U$, in your notation, and while $U$ is connected, it can be the case that the complement of a connected set is disconnected.

Comment: I guess you should allow arbitrary open subsets and not only Zariski open.

Comment: @JérômePoineau I suppose in the application I have in mind, I can assume $Y$ is Zariski open, but nonetheless the answer below seems to say that the result holds even if $Y$ is only open in the analytic topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at corollary 4.10 page 45 of the book of Banica and Stanasila titled Algebraic methods in the global theory of complex spaces,you will find a proof of the following .Any irreducible Stein space of dimension at least two has one end.This answers your question when X is irreducible .

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit confused, though, how their notion of "connected at the boundary" relates to my question. In that respect, Cor. I.4.14 looks more like what I want: as long as the depth of the local rings in $X \setminus Y$ is $\ge 2$, we have connectedness of $X \setminus Y$. Luckily, we can reduce to this case by taking a normalization, and then applying Prop. I.1.8, which says that as long as $\dim X \ge 2$ and $X$ is normal, we have the condition on depth required.

Comment: Connected at the boundary is the same as saying Y has one end. The number of connected components of the complement of Y in X is the number of ends of Y. Hence corollary 4.10 applies .